# Use result of of query of one table/entity to query another entity/table

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

I have two tables represented by two entities :

```
        @Entity
    public class HostEntity
    {
        @NotNull
        private String myGroup;

        @Id
        @NotNull
        private String host;

        @NotNull
        private long inGroupSince;
}
```

and

```
    @Entity
    public class GroupEntity
    {
        @NotNull
        private String groupId;

        @Id
        @NotNull
        private String propertiesStr;
}
```

I have **crudRepository** for each entity/table.

So, given two numbers ,**startTime** and **finishTime** ,and two strings ,**stringA** and **stringB** first - get all HostEntity.myGroup (lets call this **ListA**) such that HostEntity.inGroupSince is between startTime and finishTine, and then , return all GroupEntity.groupId such that GroupEntity.groupdId is in  **ListA** and GroupEntity.propertiesStr containt stringA and StringB

**What would be the best way to achieve that ? I can do it in one query ?**

Im working in **Spring Boot** with **crudRepository** and kinda new to it.

I can use **@query** annotations in the repostiroy , for example I got the following code :

```
@Repository
@Profile(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)
public interface IGroupsRepositoryDev extends IGroupsRepository
{
    @Query("SELECT j FROM GroupEntity j WHERE LOWER(j.propertiesStr) LIKE %?1%  and LOWER(j.propertiesStr) LIKE %?2% and LOWER(j.propertiesStr) LIKE %?3%"
        + " and LOWER(j.propertiesStr) LIKE %?4% and LOWER(j.propertiesStr) LIKE %?5% and LOWER(j.propertiesStr) LIKE %?6% and LOWER(j.propertiesStr) LIKE %?7%"
        + " and LOWER(j.propertiesStr) LIKE %?8% and LOWER(j.propertiesStr) LIKE %?9% and LOWER(j.propertiesStr) LIKE %?10% and LOWER(j.propertiesStr) LIKE %?11% ")
    List<UUID> findByProperties(String property1,String property2,String property3,String property4,String property5,String property6
        ,String property7,String property8,String property9,String property10,String property11);

}
```

which return every GroupEntity such that GroupEntity.propertiesStr containts 11 strings inside of it

**UPDATE**

I used the following as suggested below :

```
    @Query(" SELECT groupId from GroupEntity where groupId IN (SELECT myGroup FROM HostEntity WHERE inGroupSince > ?12 AND inGroupSince < ?13) "
       + "AND LOWER(propertiesStr) LIKE %?1%  and LOWER(propertiesStr) LIKE %?2% and LOWER(propertiesStr) LIKE %?3%"
       + " and LOWER(propertiesStr) LIKE %?4% and LOWER(propertiesStr) LIKE %?5% and LOWER(propertiesStr) LIKE %?6% and LOWER(propertiesStr) LIKE %?7%"
       + " and LOWER(propertiesStr) LIKE %?8% and LOWER(propertiesStr) LIKE %?9% and LOWER(propertiesStr) LIKE %?10% and LOWER(propertiesStr) LIKE %?11% ")
   List<String> findByPropertiesBetweenTime(String property1,String property2,String property3,String property4,String property5,String property6
       ,String property7,String property8,String property9,String property10,String property11,long st,long ft);
```

and I put it inside GroupEntity repository, but its not working . what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

> [...] get all HostEntity.myGroup (lets call this ListA) such that HostEntity.inGroupSince is between startTime and finishTine [...]

```
SELECT myGroup FROM HostEntity WHERE inGroupSince > startTime AND inGroupSince < finishTime
```

> [...] then , return all GroupEntity.groupId such that GroupEntity.groupdId is in ListA [...]

Use above SELECT as inner select:

```
SELECT groupId FROM GroupEntity 
WHERE 
  groupId IN (SELECT myGroup FROM HostEntity WHERE inGroupSince > startTime AND inGroupSince < finishTime)
```

> [...] and GroupEntity.propertiesStr containt stringA and StringB [...]

Add LIKEs:

```
SELECT groupId FROM GroupEntity 
WHERE 
  groupId IN (SELECT myGroup FROM HostEntity WHERE inGroupSince > startTime AND inGroupSince < finishTime)
AND propertiesStr LIKE '%stringA%' 
AND propertiesStr LIKE '%stringB%'
```

Comment: thanks, but in which repository should i put it? it doesnt matter?

Comment: Sorry, I am not that familar with Spring Boot, but using above query with the @query annotation like in your example seems plausible.

Answer (score 0):

okie !!! got it to work !!

used the following query :

```
@Query("select ge from GroupEntity ge where ge.groupId in ( select k.myGroup from HostEntity k where k.inGroupSince > ?1 and k.inGroupSince < ?2 ) "
       + "and ge.propertiesStr like %?3% and ge.propertiesStr like %?4% and ge.propertiesStr like %?5% and ge.propertiesStr like %?6% and ge.propertiesStr like %?7% "
       + "and ge.propertiesStr like %?8% and ge.propertiesStr like %?9% and ge.propertiesStr like %?10% and ge.propertiesStr like %?11% and ge.propertiesStr like %?12% "
       + " and ge.propertiesStr like %?13%")
    List<GroupEntity> findGrpWithPropertiesBetweenTime(long st,long ft,String property1,String property2,String property3,String property4,String property5,String property6
       ,String property7,String property8,String property9,String property10,String property11);
```